# Server app for WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I been trying to get my WP7 app on the marked, but it is rejected because a server app that the WP7 app is using, is falling on there test PC.

the test team has downloaded and installed the server app, but when it starts up, it failes
The error messages I get from the App Team is this : “the error message on the Media Center: “PROGRAM NOT RESPONDING. 
The Tokotech MediaCenter Server program has stopped responding and will be returned to Windows Media Center”

I have tried to install and start it up on so many different pc’s, on my dev pc, on a completely new and clean installation, as admin, and normal user, on a English installation,
 and other language installation and so on. I simple can't reproduce this error , it just works!!

Could anyone please try to download and install the server app on a Win 7 with Media Center, start Media center up, and see if the server app will start up, and if not provide me with 
a copy of the Application Event Log, then Media Center Event Log and the logfile.txt found here: C:\Users[UserName]\AppData\Local\MediaCenterServer

It can be downloaded her:  http://www.tokotech.net/software/MediaCenterRemote/setup.exe  and installed on a windows 7 PC with Media Center

Thank you very much!

Torben Koefoed

Anyone Please !!!

Comment: If this is a Windows Phone app, why is there a PC install? Have you read the certification requirements for Marketplace fully?

Comment: It is a Server app that a WP app is using. The WP app is rejected from the Marketplace because the Server app is failing, not because the WP app is.

Comment: Did you provide a Technical Exception per [requirement 5.1.4 of the certification requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh184840%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, I have provide a detail instruction, and the team have downloaded and installed the server app, but is unable to start it up on there pc.

Comment: Does you application respond if the server application is not running?

Comment: yes, der wp app is fine, is show a message  with info to ensure that the server app is running, and how to connect. again the problem is the server app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the test team is using a 64bit version of windows, and the server app is only for 32 bit.